# Web browser control in Adobe Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: mobile, adobe, flash-builder

I'm trying to add a web browser control in Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 to a mobile application.

So far, all I can find on google is to add `xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"` to my view and use `<mx:HTML>` but I'm only getting graph objects.

Anyone know if a browser control is available and where to find it?

This is my view declaration:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" title="myView">
```

Comment: I've found what seems to work finally, here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7ff9.html